# Trouble converting PDF Join Script from 2.7 to 3.10

Tags: python, pdf

The Python script below has worked for me in converting multiple PDF documents to a single PDF when running on Python 2.7. I'm now trying to use it on 3.10 and am getting errors.

I believe I've conquered most of them, especially changing print to print( and disabling imports of CoreFoundation and Quartz.CoreGraphics.

It seems that the only remaining error is:

> line 85, in main
> writeContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault,
> arg, len(arg), False), None, None) NameError: name
> 'CGPDFContextCreateWithURL' is not defined

If I declare CGPDFContextCreateWithURL as an empty global, the error shifts to CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation. Declare that and the error is kCFAllocatorDefault.

Here's how I'm trying to handle those.

> global CGPDFContextCreateWithURL CGPDFContextCreateWithURL = ""

I don't understand that entire line so any help in making it right would be appreciated.

```
#
# join
#   Joing pages from a a collection of PDF files into a single PDF file.
#
#   join [--output <file>] [--shuffle] [--verbose]"
#
#   Parameter:
#
#   --shuffle
#   Take a page from each PDF input file in turn before taking another from each file.
#   If this option is not specified then all of the pages from a PDF file are appended
#   to the output PDF file before the next input PDF file is processed.
#
#   --verbose
#   Write information about the doings of this tool to stderr.
#
import sys
import os
import getopt
import tempfile
import shutil
# from CoreFoundation import *
# from Quartz.CoreGraphics import *

global verbose
verbose = False


def createPDFDocumentWithPath(path):
    if verbose:
        print("Creating PDF document from file %s" % (path))
    return CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault, path, len(path), False))

def writePageFromDoc(writeContext, doc, pageNum):

    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(doc, pageNum)
    if page:
        mediaBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox)
        if CGRectIsEmpty(mediaBox):
            mediaBox = None
            
        CGContextBeginPage(writeContext, mediaBox)
        CGContextDrawPDFPage(writeContext, page)
        CGContextEndPage(writeContext)
        if verbose:
            print("Copied page %d from %s" % (pageNum, doc))

def shufflePages(writeContext, docs, maxPages):
    
    for pageNum in xrange(1, maxPages + 1):
        for doc in docs:
            writePageFromDoc(writeContext, doc, pageNum)
                
def append(writeContext, docs, maxPages):

    for doc in docs:
        for pageNum in xrange(1, maxPages + 1) :
            writePageFromDoc(writeContext, doc, pageNum)

def main(argv):

    global verbose

    # The PDF context we will draw into to create a new PDF
    writeContext = None

    # If True then generate more verbose information
    source = None
    shuffle = False
    
    # Parse the command line options
    try:
        options, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "o:sv", ["output=", "shuffle", "verbose"])

    except getopt.GetoptError:
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)

    for option, arg in options:

        if option in ("-o", "--output") :
            if verbose:
                print("Setting %s as the destination." % (arg))
            writeContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault, arg, len(arg), False), None, None)

        elif option in ("-s", "--shuffle") :
            if verbose :
                print("Shuffle pages to the output file.")
            shuffle = True

        elif option in ("-v", "--verbose") :
            print("Verbose mode enabled.")
            verbose = True

        else :
            print("Unknown argument: %s" % (option))
    
    if writeContext:
        # create PDFDocuments for all of the files.
        docs = map(createPDFDocumentWithPath, args)
        
        # find the maximum number of pages.
        maxPages = 0
        for doc in docs:
            if CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(doc) > maxPages:
                maxPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(doc)
    
        if shuffle:
            shufflePages(writeContext, docs, maxPages)
        else:
            append(writeContext, docs, maxPages)
        
        CGPDFContextClose(writeContext)
        del writeContext
        #CGContextRelease(writeContext)
    
def usage():
    print("Usage: join [--output <file>] [--shuffle] [--verbose]")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: I guess the issue might be commenting out `# from CoreFoundation import *` and `# from Quartz.CoreGraphics import *`. Missing names  comes  from these packages. Why did you disabled it? Was it because its not working in python 3*. In that case perhaps you should search for a new version of these packages.

Comment: I disabled them when they were named as the source for errors. I didn't know if they were somehow added into v3.

Now I have installed Quartz.CoreGraphics but the import gets an error that the module is not found. Reinstalling gets a message that the Requirement is already satisfied.

Apparently foundations are installed along with Python. I can't find a separate installation for Python 3. With that line re-enabled I get the module not found error there too.

Comment: How do you install/reinstall this Quartz.CoreGraphics? Please provide exact commands and errors.

Comment: I installed Quartz.CoreGraphics using `pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz` and it seemed to install just fine, but in my script the import error is that the module was not found. Trying the install a second time with  `pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz` is when I got the “message that the Requirement is already satisfied.” message.

Comment: Today I installed Python 3.11 and confirmed that it's the running version, then ran `pip3 install -U pyobjc`. That installation included `Downloading pyobjc_framework_Quartz-8.5.1-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl (226 kB)`. And still I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jamescook/Desktop/join.py", line 23, in <module>
    from CoreGraphics import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CoreGraphics'